# Jenkins on unix executing script on windows server

Tags: sql, sql-server, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a CI environment set up that build my project. It creates a set of sql server files, that i want to to send to my windows server. For that im looking into using scp, by installing copssh.

```
scp -r /file_in_unix/ user@windows_hostname:/cygdrive/c/
```

I want to execute a batch file on the windows server, but dont know how to do this?

any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553588/run-batch-scripts-on-a-remote-server-windows-from-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Quite fast workaround is just to connect your Windows machine to Jenkins as another node. Your current unix job can trigger this job after successful execution.