# PhpStorm: Algorithm negotiation fail

Tags: windows, phpunit, phpstorm

I've a remote server where I host my projects. And I'm using my PhpStorm locally, so every time I save, it synchronizes automatically with the remote server.

However, I failed to configure PhpStorm to run PHPUnit on the remote server.

Under `Configure Remote PHP Interpreter` I fill out the right information (Host, User name, and Password).

The error I'm having is `"Algorithm negotiation fail"` when I validate and `"Test SFTP Connection: Connection to 'id address' failed. Connection failed"` when I try to specify the path of PHP interpreter.

How do I fix that ?

Comment: Please refer to this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25360

Comment: Also related (how it can be fixed from server side): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424621/algorithm-negotiation-fail-ssh-in-jenkins

Comment: Try Tools | Deployment | Configuration | Advanced settings -> Always use LIST command, might be helpful.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved this problem by adding

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

to

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and after that, I restart sshd

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: I had the same problem after creating a new vagrant box, and can confirm this works for me.

Comment: Actualy `KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` is enough (for me at least)

Comment: I just tried this solution, I'm not having the algorithm error but ssh is blocked. I always have a "connection refused" when trying to connect with ssh...

Comment: Worked with Debian 8 openssh/sftp-server, thank you.

Comment: This worked for me too. What does the line "do/mean"?

Comment: @Zahrec read https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=Debian+7.7.0&arch=default&format=html

Answer (score 8):

Just upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04 and encountered this issue, the "Algorithm negotiation fail" in PHPStorm 8.0.3.

The problem is with the jsch-0.1.51.jar library. If you overwrite the jsch-0.1.51.jar file with the latest from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/ (currently jsch-0.1.54.jar) and restart, it should be fine. No need to add insecure algorithms to your ssh daemon.

Answer (score 2):

As **Guillaume Fache** proposed, minimal configuration for PhpStorm is:

`KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`

but `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` use:

1) `1024 bits modulus` - breakable, marked as `insecure`

2) `SHA-1` - breakable, confirmed collision attack possibility

---

**conclusion:**

use public/private key pair - more secure and no needs to save or type password

[image]

Answer (score 1):

edit this file :

```
sudo /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

add this line :

```
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

and restart :

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

It works for me!