# Arch Linux ARMv7 - Pi4J build with maven failed at JNI

Tags: linux, maven, archlinux, raspberry-pi2, archlinux-arm

I am trying to build Pi4J on Raspberry Pi2 model B with Arch linux ARM installed. Everything works fine, except for the build of the JNI natural libraries. Here is the error message (and part of the log):

```
    [INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (build-native-so) @ pi4j-native ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

build-libpi4j.so:
     [echo] Building native libpi4j shared library for ABI: hard-float
  [sshexec] Connecting to 192.168.178.94:22
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Pi4J :: Parent POM ................................. SUCCESS [01:04 min]
[INFO] Pi4J :: JNI Native Library ......................... FAILURE [ 18.906 s]
[INFO] Pi4J :: Java Library (Core) ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Pi4J :: GPIO Extension ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Pi4J :: Device Abstractions ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Pi4J :: Java Examples .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Pi4J :: OSGi Service ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Pi4J :: Distribution ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:50 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-11T20:50:37+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/29M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (build-native-so) on project pi4j-native: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] /media/temp/pi4j-arch/pi4j-native/build.xml:10: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (build-native-so) on project pi4j-native: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/temp/pi4j-arch/pi4j-native/build.xml:10: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/temp/pi4j-arch/pi4j-native/build.xml:10: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AbstractAntMojo.executeTasks(AbstractAntMojo.java:131)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:98)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/temp/pi4j-arch/pi4j-native/build.xml:10: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
        at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:508)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:418)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AbstractAntMojo.executeTasks(AbstractAntMojo.java:118)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: /media/temp/pi4j-arch/pi4j-native/build.xml:10: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.execute(SSHExec.java:188)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:416)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:520)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:286)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:150)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHBase.openSession(SSHBase.java:212)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.execute(SSHExec.java:158)
        ... 66 more
```

I tried everything I could figure out, but I cannot make it work. Please help :)

**EDIT:**

After some further investigation, I am starting to have an idea about what these messages mean and how it works. This is the part of the build.xml that gives the error:

```
            <!-- ensure the target directory is empty on the Raspberry Pi -->
            <sshexec host="${pi-host}" port="${pi-port}" username="${pi-user}"
                    password="${pi-password}" trust="true" failonerror="true"
                    verbose="true" command="rm --recursive --force ${pi-dirBuildTemp}" />
```

And to be exact, it is the line starting with "verbose".  I tried editing the command, removing parts of it... Nothing helps. I tried removing the whole block of code, leaving the others (that look really like that) and the error then is on the last line of the next block. Here is the whole /media/temp/pi4j-arch/pi4j-native/build.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="pi4j-native" default="build-libpi4j.so" basedir=".">
    <target name="build-libpi4j.so">

        <echo message="Building native libpi4j shared library for ABI: ${pi-abi}"/>

                <!-- ensure the target directory is empty on the Raspberry Pi -->
                <sshexec host="${pi-host}" port="${pi-port}" username="${pi-user}"
                        password="${pi-password}" trust="true" failonerror="true"
                        verbose="true" command="rm --recursive --force ${pi-dirBuildTemp}" />

                <!-- ensure the target directory exists on the Raspberry Pi -->
                <sshexec host="${pi-host}" port="${pi-port}" username="${pi-user}"
                        password="${pi-password}" trust="true" failonerror="false"
                        verbose="true" command="mkdir --parents ${pi-dirBuildTemp}" />

                <!-- copy all the necessary source files to the Raspberry Pi -->
                <scp todir="${pi-user}:${pi-password}@${pi-host}:${pi-dirBuildTemp}"
                        port="${pi-port}" trust="true" verbose="true" failonerror="true">
                        <fileset dir="src/main/native" />
                </scp>

                <!-- download and compile the 'wiringPi.a' native static library on the Raspberry
                        Pi platform -->
                <sshexec host="${pi-host}" port="${pi-port}" username="${pi-user}"
                        password="${pi-password}" trust="true" failonerror="true"
                        verbose="true" command="cd ${pi-dirBuildTemp}; sudo chmod +x wiringpi-build.sh; ./wiringpi-build.sh" />

                <!-- compile the 'lib4j.so' JNI native shared library on the Raspberry
                        Pi platform -->
                <sshexec host="${pi-host}" port="${pi-port}" username="${pi-user}"
                        password="${pi-password}" trust="true" failonerror="true"
                        verbose="true" command="cd ${pi-dirBuildTemp}; make clean; make all" />

                <!-- copy the compiled 'lib4j.so' JNI native shared library back -->
                <scp
                        file="${pi-user}:${pi-password}@${pi-host}:${pi-dirBuildTemp}/libpi4j.so"
                        todir="${project-build-directory}/${pi-abi}/" port="${pi-port}" trust="true"
                        verbose="true" failonerror="true">
                </scp>

                <!-- remove the temporary target directory from the Raspberry Pi  -->
                <sshexec host="${pi-host}" port="${pi-port}" username="${pi-user}"
                        password="${pi-password}" trust="true" failonerror="true"
                        verbose="true" command="rm --recursive --force ${pi-dirBuildTemp}" />

    </target>
</project>
```

Maybe the problem is not in the code itself, but in the sshexec command. But I still haven't understood how exactly it works and what might be the problem. Tomorrow I will try to remove the variables and put the values there, just for the sake of the experiment.

**EDIT2:** I tested it... Still the same error at the same place...

If anyone has any ideas, please share.

**EDIT3:**

Thank you very much, prunge! Now I am a few steps ahead! I did both of the things you suggested, as with the first one it didn't work (But I forgot to restart SSH when trying, so maybe it would work).

Now I get another error, on another step... I get only one result when googled it, but I couldn't find the file they were talking about:
https://github.com/rm-hull/wiringPi/issues/2
And I am not sure if this is exactly the same issue.

Here is the error:

```
fatal: destination path 'wiringPi' already exists and is not an empty directory.
[UnInstall]
wiringPi Build script
=====================

The wiringPi I2C helper libraries will not be built.

WiringPi library
[UnInstall]
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
[Install]

GPIO Utility
[Link]
gpio.o: In function `main':
gpio.c:(.text.startup+0x194): undefined reference to `wiringPiSetupPiFaceForGpioProg'
gpio.c:(.text.startup+0x670): undefined reference to `gertboardSPISetup'
gpio.c:(.text.startup+0x684): undefined reference to `gertboardAnalogWrite'
gpio.c:(.text.startup+0x884): undefined reference to `gertboardSPISetup'
gpio.c:(.text.startup+0x894): undefined reference to `gertboardAnalogRead'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'gpio' failed
make: *** [gpio] Error 1

Make Failed...
Please check the messages and fix any problems. If you're still stuck,
then please email all the output and as many details as you can to
  projects@drogon.net

      [ant] Exiting /media/temp/pi4j-arch/pi4j-native/build.xml.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Pi4J :: Parent POM ................................. SUCCESS [01:07 min]
[INFO] Pi4J :: JNI Native Library ......................... FAILURE [04:05 min]
[INFO] Pi4J :: Java Library (Core) ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Pi4J :: GPIO Extension ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Pi4J :: Device Abstractions ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Pi4J :: Java Examples .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Pi4J :: OSGi Service ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Pi4J :: Distribution ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 05:41 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-13T17:01:08+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/30M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (build-native-so) on project pi4j-native: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] /media/temp/pi4j-arch/pi4j-native/build.xml:27: Remote command failed with exit status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (build-native-so) on project pi4j-native: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/temp/pi4j-arch/pi4j-native/build.xml:27: Remote command failed with exit status 1
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/temp/pi4j-arch/pi4j-native/build.xml:27: Remote command failed with exit status 1
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AbstractAntMojo.executeTasks(AbstractAntMojo.java:131)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:98)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/temp/pi4j-arch/pi4j-native/build.xml:27: Remote command failed with exit status 1
        at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:508)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:418)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AbstractAntMojo.executeTasks(AbstractAntMojo.java:118)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: /media/temp/pi4j-arch/pi4j-native/build.xml:27: Remote command failed with exit status 1
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.executeCommand(SSHExec.java:250)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.execute(SSHExec.java:162)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:416)
        ... 53 more
```

I really don't get how this works, I don't see anywhere the things written in the comments (in the build.xml file)... Here is the part of build.xml that is causing the error:

```
<!-- download and compile the 'wiringPi.a' native static library on the Raspberry
        Pi platform -->
<sshexec host="${pi-host}" port="${pi-port}" username="${pi-user}"
        password="${pi-password}" trust="true" failonerror="true"
        verbose="true" command="cd ${pi-dirBuildTemp};  sudo chmod +x wiringpi-build.sh; ./wiringpi-build.sh" />
```

I can't find the wiringpi-build.sh ...

Thanks and regards,
Krum

Comment: You are trying to call an sshexec but you will get `/media/temp/pi4j-arch/pi4j-native/build.xml:10: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail`?

Comment: I am fairly new to linux (this is one of the first times I am using it at all) and I don't really understand this... Why is this happening and how can I avoid it? If needed, I can post step-by-step what I did...

edit: In the guide I was following it's written that you need an SSH connection to build the JNI native library. 

https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j/blob/master/BUILD.INSTRUCTIONS
//
https://github.com/glnds/pi4j-arch

Comment: Actually, the second link is the one I am using:

http://github.com/glnds/pi4j-arch 

I guess the important part is from step 6 to step 9.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's failing to talk to your Pi via SSH protocol.

If you haven't already, you might want to try installing the [unlimited strength encryption policy files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) into your JDK/JRE you are running Maven from.  This will allow more algorithms to be negotiated when connecting via SSH.

An alternative is to change SSHD configuration files on you Pi to allow some algorithms JSCH from your JDK/JRE supports.  Details for doing this is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424621/algorithm-negotiation-fail-ssh-in-jenkins).

Comment: I don't have 15 rep and I can't upvote your answer :/