# scripting in jenkins for deployment

Tags: linux, jenkins, deployment, scripting, continuous-integration

I have my jenkins installed on windows server, configured with git.
Currently using deploy to container plugin to deploy build to remote hosts. now instead of deploying using plugin, i want to write a shell script which will deploy war in post build action. my remote machine is linux machine (Centos).

gone through link 
[Run batch scripts on a remote server (windows) from jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553588/run-batch-scripts-on-a-remote-server-windows-from-jenkins)
but not a great help.
any help will be appreciated.

Thanks